# Multivariate FindFormula?

Tags: fitting

I am using Mathematica Online and want to do FindFormula with two independent variables, but I cannot figure out if it's possible and if so what the syntax is.

Here's my dataset:

```
data={{2.3,-0.1,-2.05849405138301},{1.4,7.7,7.00640856736182},{3.3,12.8,12.1068500585515},{-3.4,-7.2,-6.50610595480303},{-1.1,-11.5,-10.8068442167287},{3.2,11.5,10.806842689288},{-2.0,1.3,4.70385742174877},{2.0,11.1,10.4068377070671},{-1.5,-13.1,-12.4068507753869},{-0.8,3.8,6.79434740875561},{-1.8,-7.4,-6.70624196652605},{-2.9,2.8,11.6822384479537},{1.0,-4.7,-9.41802708548706},{1.0,-5.8,-11.6060368509831},{-1.7,-10.7,-10.0068302789121},{0.9,1.5,0.731545997595014},{-0.9,-13.1,-12.4068547636833},{2.4,5.3,4.60184961194878},{2.9,5.6,4.90314812454031},{0.5,-6.8,-9.93828368999231},{-2.1,-7.4,-6.70624143734462},{-1.4,-0.7,0.371891057695928},{-3.1,-2.3,-1.5014297557795},{-2.6,3.2,12.170583680945},{1.8,7.3,6.60617775490754},{3.2,14.3,13.6068522028471},{-1.9,2.7,8.30188684174903},{-2.8,1.7,7.37391006138989},{-0.4,-1.3,-0.813351087569253},{0.5,-8.0,-11.7263426905064},{1.0,3.8,3.09572952734122},{2.0,-3.4,-10.6554293779691},{3.3,4.0,3.28836781401706},{-0.2,-12.2,-11.5768329322112},{-1.7,-13.1,-12.4068507742741},{2.2,11.6,10.9068436532994},{-2.6,1.4,5.98867503704538},{-2.9,-7.5,-6.80629958215422},{2.1,0.8,-0.373783896392874},{-0.9,-1.0,-0.18044003276124},{-0.9,-1.3,-0.513901684241189},{-3.1,2.8,12.2931252986271},{-3.4,-7.7,-7.00639988970093},{-0.3,5.7,7.11863381411943},{2.2,-1.6,-5.88686866509932},{-2.6,0.5,3.24184362700227},{-1.7,-2.3,-1.50980569187011},{1.7,-1.8,-5.40806940194445},{-0.3,-1.0,-0.614071374817392},{-2.7,0.8,4.2158285857943}};
```

I've tried:

```
fit=FindFormula[data,x]
```

and thinking I might be able to specify two independent variables I put:

```
fit=FindFormula[data,x,y]
```

but the error I get both times is "at position 1 does not have the right format. Data should be a numerical array of depth less or equal than 2."

Does this mean multivariate problems are not possible with FindFormula?

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation that would indicate that multivariate formulae are supported ... but as of 10.3.1it's still marked as experimental, so changes in the API are completely expected.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think that this is a good question.